# Cannot get base controllers to work for Codeigniter on remote server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a web app using Codeigniter 2.0.3.
I need to create base controller classes and I follow the guide made buy Phil.

```
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY
```

All works perfectly fine offline on my MAMP server. But when I upload the same code
to my Amazon EC2 server all I get is a 500 error.

On my local machine I am running MacOS 10.7.2 with PHP version 5.3.6.
On my remote server I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with PHP version 5.3.6 aswell.

The 500 error is giving me no clues on what the problem is.
The base controllers that I create are "empty" (no code other than the constructor).

Thankful for all input!

**UPDATE**

Solved the problem. It was a simple case sensitive issue. My base controller classes was named for example Public_controller but was addressed as Public_Controller in the controllers. Changed case and now it works fine.

Comment: Please check your web server logs. A 500 is *always* accompanied by an error message somewhere.

Comment: Did you check your `config.php` and `.htaccess` ?

Comment: safarov. Yes, both config.php and .htaccess is correct. @DaveRandom. Where are the web server logs located on Ubuntu?

Comment: According to [this](http://fuzzyblog.wordpress.com/2005/12/08/ubuntu-where-is-the-apache-error-log/), `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I ran vi /var/log/apache2/error.log and the file was empty unfortunately.

Comment: Solved it. It was just a case sensitive issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was a simple case sensitive issue. My base controller classes was named for example Public_controller but was addressed as Public_Controller in the controllers. Changed case and now it works fine.